# How to disable buttons on click in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, bot-framework-composer

I want to disable the button once clicked in Webchat/Directline channel.
Once a user has clicked on a button, that button should get disabled to prevent duplicate usage of the button.

Comment: Please check the following link. https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1427

Answer (score 0):

In case it was missed in the linked GitHub issue, using the method described in the BotFramework-WebChat sample [05.custom.components/l.disable-adaptive-cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/main/samples/05.custom-components/l.disable-adaptive-cards/index.html) will achieve this for you.

In short, you are creating an attachment middleware that filters incoming attachments on their type. Internally, when Web Chat detects you have clicked the adaptive card button the to-be rendered HTML for the adaptive card is then given the `disabled` tag.

I've tested this many times and it works. It should for you, as well.